# Musical Practice and Performance self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: None of our really good questions have been selected, IMO.

Comment: @MatthewRead That's the beauty of random selection. :) Think of it as a chance to examine the less-than-great side of the site and see if it can be improved.

Answer (score 5):

[What are the benefits of guitars with fanned frets?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6085/what-are-the-benefits-of-guitars-with-fanned-frets)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Interesting to guitarists as commentary on Equipment... and does reference string "tension & scale length" which is applicable to all stringed instruments in some way; but not much in the way of actual music though.

Comment: The question and especially its answer could be of great value to guitarists who wish to know about the subject.

Comment: It's a question that brings focus to a sort of fretting that I even didn't know exists! Very interresting. And the answers gives excellent examples of different models - with pictures! This is definetly a question/answers that "makes the internet better".

Answer (score 4):

[Is Beethoven's title "Sonata quasi una Fantasia" an oxymoron, and does the title instruct how to perform it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/is-beethovens-title-sonata-quasi-una-fantasia-an-oxymoron-and-does-the-title)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this question and its answers are really great. Useful to those playing the piece or listening to the piece. More Beethoven!

Answer (score 3):

[How is electronic music performed live?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/how-is-electronic-music-performed-live)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This one was surprisingly interesting once the sense of the question was "cracked".

Answer (score 2):

[Learning 4/5 trills on the piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/learning-4-5-trills-on-the-piano)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I now wish I had deleted my answer earlier. The timing would be too transparent now.

Answer (score 2):

[Percussion notes in the vocals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/percussion-notes-in-the-vocals)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this is a dumb question. But the answerers dealt with it tastefully.

Answer (score 2):

[Why do these two songs seem impressive yet are easy to "sing"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/why-do-these-two-songs-seem-impressive-yet-are-easy-to-sing)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It may not have appeared this way initially, but this question was quite answerable, and the answer is excellent.  I wouldn't mind seeing more questions asking about other musical phenomena in culture.

Answer (score 2):

[Can anyone learn to sing higher?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/will-i-ever-be-able-to-sing-higher)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question and its answers highlight one of the difficulties with the site.  Some performance-related questions cannot be answered satisfactorily in any kind of question-and-answer text format.  The answers reflect this problem; I would hate to have a lot of questions whose best answer is "find a teacher."  The answers show effort, but I don't think a satisfactory answer is truly possible here.

Comment: I think the answers here are admirable because of that very difficulty. While they all firmly suggest personal instruction, they go on to describe the what and why of the instruction: identifying one's range, warmup exercises, abdominal breathing.

Answer (score 1):

[Tools to create drums backing track for non-drummer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/tools-to-create-drums-backing-track-for-non-drummer)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[How important is it for a guitar player to know the notes which make up a chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/how-important-is-it-for-a-guitar-player-to-know-the-notes-which-make-up-a-chord)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question is both basic and vague.  The answers vary in quality.

Answer (score -3):

[Where can i find good transcriptions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/where-can-i-find-good-transcriptions)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question was too vague and invited a type of "shopping list."  I wouldn't call this question, or any question, "embarrassing," but it is not a model of questions moving toward expert-level.