# Stack Improvement Drive - Musical Practice and Performance

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Greetings from Stack Exchange HQ! I am here to check in on the site and see if there’s any way the team from Stack Exchange can help you improve it. Note that this is a more hands-on, site-by-site and case-by-case basis evaluation, ***not*** related to the **[Quality](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/362/28) [Evaluations](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/music-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical)** already done on this and other sites.

We’ve started keeping an eye on certain metrics and now after a couple months of tracking the data, we have a few areas that we think Music.SE can improve in. Here are the two areas that have caught our attention:

- Between October and November, your visitors per day has dropped from 2600 to 2412
- Between October and November, your questions per day has dropped from 2.6 to 2.4

I know those may not seem like big dips, but there’s no reason we can’t work towards improving them. The site is actually *just* a little below average compared to other sites near its age, and I think it can be pushed to *above* average with a little bit of attention paid to these two areas. Here are some resources and ideas for enabling improvement:

- To improve visitors per day, try sharing your questions via other social media sites you use (click on the “share” button below any question). There is a badge for sharing that can be awarded multiple times: the **[Announcer](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer)** badge. We can start a contest wherein users who get the Announcer badge get a prize.
- To improve the number of questions asked per day, we can start hosting **[Topic of the Week](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-august-29)** events, where tags are chosen by the community and any questions within that tag during a set period of time are eligible for a prize.

We are relying on you, the core user community, to decide whether or not either of these ideas are worth implementing. If so, we will spearhead the effort! You have our attention and also a modest budget with which to launch some of these initiatives.

If you want to do an **Announcer badge reward**, or start a **Topic of the Week campaign**, please leave an answer saying so!

If any core users of Music.SE have **any other ideas** for improving on these metrics, **please leave an answer to this meta post**.

Additionally, we know you are excited about the potential for our sites but please keep this meta post focused on things you, as the collective community, can do as opposed to feature requests or larger branding campaigns. We want your ideas, so please make them separate meta posts so we can keep all these discussions focused!

---

**UPDATE:** Both a [Topic of the Week](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/topic-of-the-week-contest) contest and [Announcer Badge Reward](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/announcer-badge-reward) have been started. Please leave suggestions for future topics of the week!

Comment: Topic of the Week could definitely be helpful, since I think a lot of our more experienced users are at a bit of a loss for questions.  Having one area to focus on and think about might help that.  The Announcer idea is interesting too, I just wonder if many of us have a significant number of musically-inclined friends who would also follow such a link.  I suppose I could always try to interest the Twittersphere at large :P.  (As an aside I just got an electric piano and started playing again, so hopefully I can contribute more questions than I have in the past.)

Comment: @MatthewRead I can get a Topic of the Week contest going today. Any suggestions on what the first topic should be? I'm inclined to start with "voice" or "composition" (or a similarly underused tag); then suggestions for topics can be posted on the Meta thread for the contest.

Answer (score 4):

I think a Topic of the Week campaign would be a great idea. I've seen it done on other sites and it seemed a good way to get users involved.  Count me in.

The only downside to this is that some are less knowledgeable in certain areas. For example, I know very little about guitars, our top tag. However, it is just one week per topic, I suppose.

Also, with only six users having gotten the Announcer badge, I'd say we could definitely work on this. I've never heard of an Announcer badge reward, but it's a good idea.

As a side note, I'm supposing were also doing the "hats" thing (for lack of a better term) per this [chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/440/2012/11/27).

Comment: We've never given an award for announcer badges, as far as I know, so this would be a NEW thing, debuting on THIS site!