# Topic of the Week Contest (UPDATED Feb. 4th)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is a quick way to both expand and enrich the scope of the site, as well as generate new questions.

This is also related to the [Stack Improvement Drive](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/stack-improvement-drive-musical-practice-and-performance?cb=1).

**How it works:** One topic will be designated each week. Each person who [asks a question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize. Users can ask as many questions in the topic as they like, thus entering them into the contest multiple times. All the questions must remain open and with a score of 0 or higher. The current topic is listed below.

**How to enter:** [Ask a question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly. Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win one of the following prizes:

- If your country is regularly serviced by an online Amazon store without exorbitant shipping costs, you can choose an item of your choice (under $50 USD)
- If your country is not serviced by an online Amazon store, you will receive a Stack Exchange swag package of exclusive merchandise.

The difference in prizes is due to the difference in cost for us to ship to various parts of the world.

The question must have a score of 0 or greater and not be closed or deleted to be eligible. **Users may only win once in a four week period.**

**Choosing the topic of the week:** If you have suggestions for a future topic, **please leave them as answers to this post.** Topics must be trackable with a tag, and that tag should have a tag wiki filled out. Please do leave topic suggestions, and if you leave suggestions that don't have tag wikis, try to fill them out!

---

**Current Topic: [sheet-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sheet-music)**

Any questions correctly tagged [sheet-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sheet-music) will be eligible for the prize. Questions posted before **Monday, February 12, 2012 at 5 AM UTC** will be eligible. Winners will be picked and notified on Mondays at approximately **2 PM UTC**.

---

**WINNERS:**

- Dec. 12th: [segiddins](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/2995/segiddins) - [voice question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7976/how-can-i-do-rough-vocals-without-hurting-my-voice)
- Dec. 19th: [Shimmy](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/530/shimmy) - [notation question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8031/what-does-1-x-tacet-mean)
- Dec. 26th: [luser droog](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1344/luser-droog) - [composition question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/what-is-sonata-allegro-form-and-what-other-similar-forms-should-i-be-aware-of)
- Jan. 2nd: [gingerbreadboy](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/594/gingerbreadboy) - [rock n roll question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/what-makes-the-4-4-back-beat-rhythm-of-rock-n-roll-so-compelling)
- Jan. 9th: [Matthew read](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/28/matthew-read) - [beethoven question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/how-can-i-play-fur-elise-well)
- Jan. 21st: [Luke](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1678/luke) - [drums question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9377/what-do-multiple-ls-and-rs-beneath-a-note-mean)
- Jan. 28th: [berry120](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/5600/berry120) - [piano question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9472/is-there-any-repertoire-that-makes-explicit-use-of-the-sostenuto-pedal)
- Feb. 4th: [Dr Mayhem](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/104/dr-mayhem) - [guitar question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9525/how-can-i-easily-manage-different-tunings)

Comment: Brett, did you receive my reply email?

Comment: @BrettWhite  Are items still supposed to be music-related? I noticed that that is not in this post anymore. Typo?

Comment: Got my mic, thanks Brett and SE :)

Comment: Have we ever been up to 4 QPD (since private beta)? This is awesome!

Comment: Thanks to Brett and Stack Exchange! Got my package - the JP Guitar tool is replacing a set of snips and an allan key set in my gig bag, and the Snark tuner is helping me teach my youngest guitar! :-)

Comment: Is this continuing?

Comment: Maybe not- because we're up to 3.3 questions per day  now?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [rock-n-roll](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-n-roll) once the wiki is filled-out.

I'd argue quantity over quality. We have systems in place. :)

Should we keep one suggestion per answer to lets votes sort them? Otherwise, a composer or two might work (generate more than four questions!) [beethoven](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beethoven) [brahms](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brahms) [stravinsky](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stravinsky).

---

Edit: I've lost faith in my own suggestions. [beethoven](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beethoven) hasn't inspired any questions yet. So I have very little hope for [brahms](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brahms) and [stravinsky](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stravinsky) (I already ditched [khatchaturian](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/khatchaturian)). [bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach) has a little more potential, I think (hope).

Maybe, try instruments? [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) [piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piano) [drums](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drums) [voice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice)

---

Edit: More ideas. I suppose with [sheet-music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sheet-music) were drifting towards categories. How about [theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory), [technique](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique), [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice), [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), [history](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)?

Comment: I am fine with having any of these be the topic of the week, if they get their tag wikis filled out. I think we're striving for a balance between quality and quantity; we only want a high quantity if those questions are going to be of quality, of course. That being said, the topic changes weekly, so I think we have room to move around with the kinds of things we pick.

Comment: @BrettWhite Alright, I tried my hand at a Rock-n-roll wiki. I decided the only way to make it short was to stop early. Just waiting on some peer-review...

Comment: Thank you for more topic suggestions! We were running dry. "Drums" week has started (chose that one because it's the tag most in need of questions)

Comment: I'd suggest some wind instruments also.

Answer (score 2):

It would be beneficial to choose categories that lend themselves well to more "professional-level" questions, I think.  [voice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice) had this potential, but I'm not sure [notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) really did.  I suppose someone *could* have asked about medieval notation or something non-standard, but standard notation questions tend to be fairly basic.

As for [rock-n-roll](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-n-roll) — well, I don't know.  It's not my area, so I don't have any idea which questions would be good.

My point is, quality over quantity, though we need both.

Comment: I agree 100%. Not being that knowledgeable about music, though, I'm going to have to lean on the community juuuust a little to come up with the topics (that explains the choosing of notation). I've been looking at tags that are popular, but not in the top 10 most frequented. That's how I came up with the first two. I am very open to all suggestions!

Comment: @BrettWhite [tag:composition] may produce some interesting results.  I'm interested to see what people ask.

Comment: I actually considered asking some renaissance notation questions, but I didn't get the proverbial round tuit in time.  (I've transcribed a bunch of dance music and there've definitely been judgment calls to make.)  Are there people here who can answer such questions?

Comment: @MonicaCellio One way to find out!