# Announcer Badge Reward

Tags: discussion, status-completed

In an effort to increase the number of visitors per day to the site and up the site's visibility, we will be rewarding users who receive the **[Announcer Badge](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer)** from the time of this post's publishing until the time when our visitors/day goal has been met.

The visitors/day goal for Music to reach is **three consecutive days with a minimum of 3600** visitors.

The **[Announcer Badge](https://music.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer)** is won by sharing a link to a question that is visited by 25 unique IP addresses. While this badge can be awarded multiple times, a user can only receive the award once (the nature of the prize may make multiple rewards redundant). The share tools can be found by clicking on "share" on a question's page, like so:

[image]

Winners will be rewarded with a Stack Exchange prize package.

For more information on this and other opportunities to improve Music.SE, please see the [Stack Improvement Drive](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/stack-improvement-drive-musical-practice-and-performance).

---

The following users have been rewarded:

- **[Matthew Read](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/28/matthew-read)**

Comment: Secret rewards, I like it ;) (edit: [doubly first!](http://music.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer?userid=28))

Comment: Is this still on? I got a badge recently :)

Comment: On a related note, you guys may want to reach out to the flautist community. I did try to get some flautists interested, but there are too less flute questions here to interest them. I'd participate, except that I'm an amateur with no time to play (and thus no questions or answers to contribute)

Comment: Has the VPD goal been met?

Comment: @brettwhite is this still active or can it marked as answered to clear the unanswered queue?